# google cloud vision api returns a empty result with a base 64 encoded image

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I tried to send a base64 encoded image to the google cloud vision api, but it returns an empty result. When I comment out "content = base64.b64encode(content)", it works fine.

The reasons why I am trying to use base 64 is that it should be faster.
Reference: https://medium.com/bankify-tech-blog/how-to-optimize-the-speed-of-google-vision-api-cdc5e452104b

I used the implementation of google. Reference: https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/base64

Note: Programming language is Python:

```
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

with io.open("image.jpg", 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()
    content = base64.b64encode(content)

image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
response = client.text_detection(image=image) # nur hier bottleneck
full_texts = response.full_text_annotation
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google cloud vision not accepting base64 encoded images python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695542/google-cloud-vision-not-accepting-base64-encoded-images-python)

Comment: And in Ruby: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048382/how-to-send-base64-image-to-google-cloud-vision-api-label-detection-in-ruby

Comment: I agree with @B.Go ... if we read here ... https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/gapic/v1p4beta1/types.html ... we see that types.Image.content is a stream of bytes ... not a base64 encoded string.

Comment: @B. GO No, it does not solve my question. The implementation example of google is just not working as they say it should and I am helpless at the moment.

Comment: @ Kolban But they say at https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/base64 that this is possible.